# Getting "zsh: command not found: time" when running `time` in subshell

Tags: shell, time, zsh

I installed ZSH (and Oh-My-ZSH) on a Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit machine a few days ago. I just tried to do:

```
time (time ls)
```

and got this error:

```
zsh: command not found: time
( time ls; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 64% cpu 0.002 total
```

The exact same thing works on ZSH on my Mac.

I also tried running ZSH without loading any config file, using `zsh -f -d`, but got the same error.

What could be the problem here?

---

Some more output that may help:

```
➜  ~  type -a time
time is a reserved word
➜  ~  time (type -a time)
time is a reserved word
( type -a time; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
➜  ~  time (time)
zsh: command not found: time
( time; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
➜  ~  which time
time: shell reserved word
➜  ~  time (which time)
time: shell reserved word
( which time; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
```

Comment: A simple bit googleing (googling?) yielded this bug report: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=41644

Comment: @TimLamballais, that seems to be fixed in 3.1.5, I'm on 5.0.0 (zsh 5.0.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu))

Comment: Ah I see now. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? In your examples I don't see any reason not to run time as your first command?

Comment: Anyway, does it help if you substitute `time` form `/usr/bin/time` (or wherever your binary is located?

Comment: @TimLamballais, I want to do something like `time (ls | while read line; do; time ls $line; done;)`. There was no `time` executable on the system, so I did `apt-get install time`, now I have `/usr/bin/time`, which seems to work if I use the full path.

Comment: I would suggest it might be a `$PATH` export issue then. Is the `$PATH` listed if you `export`?

Comment: @demure, I don't see how that could be a problem, but here's the output of `echo $PATH` - `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: `echo $PATH` and `export | grep PATH` have two different meanings. You can have a env var that isn't exported

Comment: @demure, ah, didn't know that! `export | grep PATH` also prints the exact same value for `PATH`.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your PATH. More so with the fact that `time` is used as a built-in rather than a reference to a binary. This apparently causes your syntax errors.

Answer (score 5):

`time` is a reserved word in zsh. It is only recognized at the beginning of a command. It's a reserved word, and not a builtin, because when you write `time foo 
| bar`, it is the compound command `foo | bar` that is timed and not just `foo`.

Where `time` isn't recognized as a reserved word, it's interpreted as the name of an external command. Your system, for whatever reason, has no `time` command installed. So commands like `\time`, `=time`, or the second `time` in `time time` try to invoke the non-existent `time` executable and you get the error message “command not found: time”.

If you want to be able to run `time (time ls)` (not that this is a useful command), install the `time` package. It's a dependency of `ubuntu-standard`, which is a sign that you should have it installed.